# I need a definition for this word

Tags: definition

I need this sentence to be defined or summarized into one or two words please. The word is

> “we will get you married”

I had a dream where my father was standing in the kitchen and he told me we are going to get you married. And I felt happy and excited in my dream. So I just need that sentence summarized so I can look it up on a dream interpretation online. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear what the question is.  It seems that you understand the meaning of this sentence. Sentences can't, in general, be reduced to one or two words.  Are you asking "What is the word for when a father organises the spouse marriage of his daughter?"   If so, please tell me what the word for it is in your native language, and look it up in a bilingual dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The direct literal interpretation is that your family will cause your marriage to happen, or that your family will assist you in overcoming any difficulties so that the marriage takes place. The sentence describes a future time wherein the action has already taken place.